# Sitecore rich text field missing the "[No text in field]" value in page editor when no data is available

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor, sitecore7.1

We have updated our project from Sitecore 6.5 to version 7.1 and noticed that rich text fields in page editor are missing the "[No text in field]" when there is no value available. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Does anyone know where this can be checked?
I assume there are some configuration files/javascript files that add this value but a long an strenuous Google search has turned up nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you check the default text value of `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/WebEdit Texts` in the Core database

Comment: I confirm /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/WebEdit Texts is the place where you need to check. I checked on 2 Sitecore 6.5 and 7.1 and  it's on both version this item.

Comment: Can you check if you have a custom renderwebediting, because on that processor is change the value from webedit texts. This one Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.RenderWebEditing on renderField pipeline

Comment: @jammykam I checked the value of the /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/WebEdit Texts item and it's set properly.

Comment: @sitecoreclimber I checked the configs (mainly web.config but also did a text search on the Website folder) and it seems that the RenderWebEditing is not overloaded.

Comment: Could this be a JavaScript related issue? I see no other place where this might fail.

Comment: Can you check with WinMerge folders from old solution with new solution,they change a lot between 6.5 and 7.1 and can be related to JS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49636/discussion-between-sitecore-climber-and-bogdan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Sitecore issue for version 7.1. Sitecore HelpDesk provided a quick fix for this.

Comment: Any chance you can share the fix ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix was contained in a binary file and I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to share it on SO (or whether I can, for that matter). If you contact Sitecore's support service I'm sure they can provide you with the fix in no time.